# Gradle version to use with Android/Cordova CLI

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I currently use Cordova CLI on Windows to build hybrid Android apps.  I am in the process of moving my development mover to a headless Ubuntu server.  Getting java, NVM, Node, Android SDK and Cordova CLI installed on Ubuntu has not been a problem.  Having done so and created the customary Cordova hello world project,

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

I proceeded to add the Android platform

```
cordova plaform add android
```

and then attempted to build

```
cordova build android
```

at which point I was told

> Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>   or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
>   in your path, or install Android Studio

Installing Gradle by following the instructions given [here](https://gradle.org/install/) - I am NOT installing Android Studio and am working on a headless Ubuntu machine so automatic Gradle installation is not an option - is not a problem.  However, it is not clear to me which version of Gradle I should install.

I do not want to break my current Cordova project so I am trying to replicate the current Windows/Cordova CLI setup as closely as I can

- Node 8.9.2
- Java 8
- Gradle ???

Dipping inside the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in my existing project I find

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

I have noted that when I compile the project at present there are some ominous warnings about features to be removed from future versions of Gradle that are shown.  I could experiment with using gradle-2.10 but it is not entirely clearr to me that it would indeed be the right version.  Hopefully, someone here will be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

First, clean up the project

```
 cordova clean android
```

Then, force the cordova to use the distribution url with the version you want, in this case: gradle-6.3

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Then, build your application.

```
cordova build android --release
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.